# In a fully normalized db, when should I use composite indices versus join tables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, indexing

So the context is that I am a Rails dev and I use PostgreSQL.

As a general rule, when should I use composite indices versus using a join table and what are the things I should consider when making that decision?

Right now, I tend to just use join tables for HABTM relations.

But want to learn more about composite indices. There a performance benefit?

What are the benefits if any?

**Edit 1**

So I made a mistake earlier. I had said 'join tables for has_many relations'. I meant to say just 'HABTM relations'. I guess I am trying to figure out if join_tables and composite indices are interchangeable? It seems to me that if I can store multiple foreign_keys in one column, why do I need a join table?

Comment: If a composite index is an index on more than one column, your question doesn't make any sense.  Maybe you should tell us what a composite index is in this context.

Comment: Can you give an example of the difference between the two scenarios you have in mind?

Comment: Tried to give some clarity by updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fully normalised database design you would never store multiple values in a single column -- it would break First Normal Form.

Always use a join table for many-many relations.

I don't think you mean a composite index -- that is a single index that includes more than one column, which you might use on the *_id and *_type columns of a table that supports a polymorphic object.

In order to join on a column containing multiple foreign keys you'd probably need a gem to support it. I don't believe activerecord does.

When would you use it? IMHO never. I can't think of a single meaningful advantage.

Comment: So in a modern day Rails app, when might I consider using a composite index?

Comment: Ahhh right. I guess I am conflating the two concepts. A composite index is simply a combination of say the primary_key + name column....versus a join table being allowing you to store several records with the 1 foreign_key. I see my mistake.